# how to use substring-after-last()

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to retrieve the name of the XML document i'm working on and I'm using the below Xpath.

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:base-uri()"/>
```

and the resule that i get is having the entire path of the document i.e. like below

```
file:///C:/Users/home/Desktop/files/document/08192014/Raw.xml
```

so to get the only name of the XML document, in Altova the intelligence  is showing some function `substring-after-last()`, i used this like below.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-after-last(fn:base-uri(),'/')"/>
```

when i run this, i was getting some error as

```
Unknown function 'substring-after-last'
    Warning location: xsl:stylesheet / xsl:template / html / body / section / div 
    / xsl:value-of / @select
    Details
        XPST0017: The function call 'substring-after-last' does not match the 
        name of a function in the static context
```

please let me know how can i fix this problem and get the file name, also the same error is thrown for `substring-before-last()` and some other functions given in Altova.

I use XSLT 2.0

when searching online I've found that there was a template created and a call was done to that template, i want to know why am I directly unable to use the given function
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `substring-after-last` function isn't part of the XPath standard, it's an Altova-specific extension function.  To use it you need to declare the Altova extension namespace with `xmlns:altova="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions"` and then refer to the function as `altova:substring-after-last`.

If you want to stick to standard XPath functions for portability then you can rewrite it in terms of regular expressions and use the `replace` function instead

```
replace(base-uri(), '^.*/', '')
```

The `*` quantifier is greedy, so this will match the longest possible substring from the start of `base-uri()` that ends with a slash, and replace it with an empty string (i.e. remove it altogether).